# SQL find value in one table in another variation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, compare

I have 2 tables like so.

```
Table1
FullName     LastName    FirstName
John Smith   Smith       John

Table2
LastName     Firstname   AKA
Smith Stein  Johnny      John the Bad Guy
```

I need to find any variation of `lastname` and `firstname` from `table1` in `table2`. However, I can't join the tables because there is nothing to join on as the names could be different. Basically, I'm trying to compare our list to a public list to see if any names match up.

I am trying this:

```
Select * 
from table1
where exists (select * 
    from table2 
    where charindex(table1.lastname, table2.lastname)>0 
        and charindex(table1.firstname,table2.firstname)>0)
```

I get returned value, but I'd like to see the values from table2 as well.

I would need to see John Smith Returned AND show that John Smith Stein was flagged in the other table. This variation of lastname would also apply to the firstname as well. That's why I can't join on any 1 specific column.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: tag your question with your db, please.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results so there is a chance that someone else has an idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its SQL 2008 R2. I'm trying to figure out how to upload a table.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are checking for an exact match between names, so why not join them?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 on t2.firstname = t1.firstname
       and t2.lastname = t2.lastname
```

Comment: the issue is that the names won't be exact. If the name John Smith is in table1, and in Table2 i have Johnny Smith Stein, i would need this to be flagged. That's why i can't join on any 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the rule is for 'similar' names but you could try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 on  
        t1.lastname = t2.lastname or t1.lastname=t2.aka or whatever other rules you want to set up
```

Comment: Also you can try using 'difference'.  The higher the number returned, the closer the strings are to each other.  Have a look at these queries: select difference('Jen R', 'Daniel Marcus')
select difference('Dan Marcus', 'Daniel Marcus')
select difference('Daniel Marcus', 'Daniel Marcus')